# xcode MainWindow.xib vs ViewController.xib, trying to delete label from viewController.xib?

Tags: iphone, xcode, mainwindow

I'm trying to understand the relationship between the ViewController xib and the MainWindows.xib?

I clicked the mainwindow xib from the project navigator a window pops up that I can draw on and then I click the viewcontroller icon and another window pops up besides. I dragged a label onto the viewcontroller.xib and now I cant delete it.

I'm trying to understand the relationship between the two

Sorry for confusing question, just trying to find my way...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select it so it's highlighted, then press backspace, which will delete it.

Comment: Can you tell me the relationship between the MainWindow and the viewcontroller, thanks.

Comment: I've figured it out. MainWindow.xib is the initial nib that gets called by the UIApplicationMain. The mainwindow.xib contains a delegate to the viewcontroller.